# Multiple animation android

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to add animation multiple views,say on 4 different imageviews, so how can i start animation on these items. The flow should be animation starts on 1 item and when it finishes animation should start on 2nd item and when this finish it should start on 3rd item.

Comment: i have tried to make two imageview  and starting animation on first item on button click. I have used animation listener to detect start and end animation event so that when first animation end i clear first animation and increase the value of an  integer variable and checks if position ==1 then it should start animation on another object. This works on 2 objects but not more than that.

Comment: @android_beginner so you want to do it with two imageviews or one imageview

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **Animation.AnimationListener** interface to keep track or monitor the animations. This listener contains three methods:
1. **onAnimationStart():** This method is called when the animation is started.
2. **onAnimationEnd():** This method is called when the animation ends.
3. **onAnimationRepeat()**: This method is called when the animation is repeated.

Create the `Animation.AnimationListener` as shown below:

```
Animation.AnimationListener animationListener = new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    };
```

Now, in order to monitor all your animations, **you need to create separate instances** of `Animation.AnimationListener` interface for each animation. In each interface's `onAnimationEnd()` method, you need to start the next animation. For example, in the Animation.AnimationListener's onAnimationEnd() method for first `ImageView` start the animation for second `ImageView`.

Comment: U mean to say that i need to make multiple animation listener ?

Comment: Yes, you need to create separate AnimationListener for each animation.

Comment: Ok thanks, i was just wondering if there is any way for doing this without multiple animation listener ?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no other way.

Comment: Your welcome. If you still have any doubts or problems feel free to ask. And if your problem has been solved please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Animator animation = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(getApplicationContext(), 
                         R.animator.selectzoom);//selectzoom is a xml file of your animation
```

To add animation to a image, based on index of a image value in imageview array

```
animation.setTarget(imageView[animaterimg]);//imageView is a array of your images views
animation.start();
```

To stop animation to a image, based on index of a image value in imageview array

```
imageView[animaterimg].clearAnimation();
imageView[animaterimg].animate().cancel();
```

selectzoom must be in Animator folder

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="1000"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"/>

    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="1000"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
        android:propertyName="scaleX"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="reverse" />

</set>
```